# p:upload file doesn't work with pdf extension neither of the rest of extension like png,docx,jpeg,gif?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

and I cant' store file more than 10Mb 
the primary problrm is why doesn't except pdf file???
this is my ManagedBean
file upload function :-

```
public void fileUploadListener(FileUploadEvent e) throws IOException, Exception {

    this.file = e.getFile();                
    File oStream = new File("c:\\test.pdf");
    courseResourceBean.update(item);
    oStream.createNewFile();
    Long sss = file.getSize();
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputstream();
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(oStream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[sss.byteValue()];
    int lenght;
    while ((lenght = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
    }
    outputStream.close();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("File Uploaded Successfully" + file.getSize()));
    String extension = file.getContentType();

}
```

file download function :-

```
public void prepDownload(Long id) throws Exception {
    File files = new File("c:\\test.pdf");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(files);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    setDownload(new DefaultStreamedContent(input, externalContext.getMimeType(files.getName()), files.getName()));
    System.out.println("PREP = " + download.getName());
}
```

and this is the xhtml page
upload :-

```
<p:outputLabel value="#{msg.courseName}, #{msg.inArabic}" style="text-align: right"/>
        <p:fileUpload value="#{courseResourceMB.file}" mode="advanced" sizeLimit="200000000000" 
                      fileUploadListener="#{courseResourceMB.fileUploadListener}" update="msg11" >


        </p:fileUpload>
```

downlad:-

```
<p:commandButton id="downloadLink" value="Download" actionListener="#{courseResourceMB.prepDownload(item.id)}" ajax="false"> 
                <p:fileDownload value="#{courseResourceMB.download}" />
            </p:commandButton>
```

Comment: In the title you state 'upload' but in the tags you have 'download'. An issue can never be related to both... If the upload fails, you cannot attempt to download it and if the upload succeeds but the download fails, it is not upload related. Please improve your question. And it is also not 'pdf' related if it also fails with other extensions

Comment: the upload files has done okay except .pdf files can't write to its file
this is the error